# insert link id as form value on click using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a bunch of links with the class name row. What I'm trying to do, is when you click one of those links with that row class, it grabs the value of its id, and inserts that into a text input on a form.

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $(".rowd").click(function() {
        $("#esptotal").val( this.id()  );
    });
});
```

to view the page, you can visit this link: http://tinyurl.com/c36s8rm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `this.id()` by `this.id`

```
$(function(){
    $(".rowd").click(function(e){
      $("#esptotal").val(this.id);
      e.preventDefault();
    }); 
});
```

Comment: these are anchor tags without preventDefault() this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$(function(){
    $(".rowd").click(function(){
        $("#esptotal").val( $(this).attr('id')  );
    }); 
});​
```

Comment: This will work. But `this.id` is just so much more elegant both in terms of readability and in terms of performance-- no need to wrap up a jQuery object just to get a node's ID.

Comment: Without preventDefault() this will not work these are anchor tags

Answer (score 0):

Sure no problem:

```
$('.rowd').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#esptotal').val($(this).attr('id'))
});
```

See the fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/yEwNm/

Comment: I did not wrap in an anonymous as I did not see a need you can always replace the $ with jQuery and it makes the code neater and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

I would change my markup to use some html5 data attributes. I think it is more what you are trying to do.. Or you could just grab the cost from the span.

```
<a href="#" class="row" data-cost="259.99">
    <div class="col4">$6001-$7000.99</div> 
    <span class="col3">$259.99</span>
    <br class="clear">
</a>


$(".row").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#esptotal").val( $(this).data("cost")  );
}); 

$(".row").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#esptotal").val( $(this).children(".col3").val()  );
});
```